# How to add columns names to a spatialpolygon based on column from a dataframe?

Tags: r, r-sp

*Dummy SpatialPolygon:*

```
x_coord <- c(16.48438,  17.49512,  24.74609, 22.59277, 16.48438)
y_coord <- c(59.736328125, 55.1220703125, 55.0341796875, 61.142578125, 59.736328125)
xym <- cbind(x_coord, y_coord)

library(sp)
p = Polygon(xym)
ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
plot(sps)
```

*Dummy dataframe:*

```
df <- data.frame (date= c("2021", "2015", "2018"),
                  value= c(100, 147, 25))
```

Basic question but how can I add the columns names of the dataframe to the spatial polygon ? (I don't need to add some value, I just want my spatialpolygon to have the field "date" and "value")

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `sp` library, but I'd think this would work if  your `data.frame` had the same number of rows as your polygon.

Comment: You can try `addAttrToGeom` from `sp`, if you have a data.frame of your polygons, then you can either run `leff_join` from `sf` (`?sf::tidyverse`) or any other method on data frames.

Comment: I'm also looking for the same answer ! Since it's easy to add a column to a SpatialPolygon by doing sps$new_column <- NA. Wouldn't it be possible to run a loop in order to insert every column from a dataframe into the spatialPolygon ?

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko I looked up the addAttrToGeom function and it worked, thx ! If you post it as an answer I'd accept it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your object (Spatial Polygons in this case) with `addAttrToGeom`

```
library(sp)
spsCRS <- CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:4326")
p = Polygon(xym)
ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
proj4string(sps) <- spsCRS
plot(sps)

df <- data.frame("ID" = 1, "Name" = "MyNewPolygon", "URL" = "http://example.org")
spsDf <- addAttrToGeom(sps, df, match.ID = "ID")
```

Which creates a new object:

```
An object of class "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
Slot "data":
  ID         Name                URL
1  1 MyNewPolygon http://example.org

Slot "polygons":
[[1]]
[...]
```